# Removing built-in Outlook from Windows 10

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I subscribe to Office 365, including Outlook. However, there's also a Windows Mail and Calendar app embedded in Windows 10, and that's a constant headache. It's automatically launched from websites that include links to send email to the website owner or support services. Whenever it launches, I am prompted to enter my password for ALL the aliases associated with my account. No matter how many times I do this, the same prompt appears. I can't close either the prompts or the application without restarting my laptop.

Making it worse, I can't find the app anywhere on my system.

I want to get rid of this embedded nightmare entirely, and if possible, reset my app associations to make Outlook 365 the default that launches from the email links on websites. Making it worse, I can't find the

Answer (score 0):

If it's not available in the "Programs and Features" list, then it might be a native app, in which case you could try searching for it in an admin session of PowerShell with:
`Get-AppxPackage`

If it happens to be there, use this to uninstall it: `Get-AppxPackage *outlook* | Remove-AppxPackage`. I merely assume it's called outlook.

Otherwise trying to set the default app in `Windows Settings > Apps > Default Apps` is probably your best bet. You'd be on the lookout for the `url:mailto` link in `Choose default apps by protocol` (at the very bottom) is my guess.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to remove the "Mail" app in windows?
If so, you may try the setps below:

1. Run Windows Power Shell as Adminstrator
2. Type "Get-AppxPackage *communi* | Remove-AppxPackage"
3. Press Enter

Hope this can be helpful.